# XPath or CSS in Selenium RC with Java is not working

Tags: java, xpath, junit, css-selectors, selenium-rc

I am trying to automate the following scenario with selenium RC:

1. Open Google home page and enter "Software" in search box and then click on search button.
2. Click on the first link of multiple links retrieved by Google search.

As I don't see either name or id attributes for these links and as this link's content is dynamic, I am trying to use XPath or CSS.

From Firebug, I got XPath and also CSS by right clicking then copy XPath, copy CSS.

```
XPATH:/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/ol/li[1]/div/span/h3/a

CSS:html body#gsr div#main div div#cnt div#nr_container div#center_col div#res.med div#search div#ires ol#rso li.g div.vsc span.tl h3.r a.l
```

I tried entering above XPath in selenium IDE in target and find button.  It worked fine
but when I use the above XPath or CSS in selenium RC as:

```
selenium.click("xpath=//html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/ol/li[1]/div/span/h3/a");
selenium.click("css=html body#gsr div#main div div#cnt div#nr_container div#center_col div#res.med div#search div#ires ol#rso li.g div.vsc span.tl h3.r a.l");
```

Both the above lines are not working and give an error.
Please suggest.

My code is as below:

```
package Eclipse_Package; 

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.*;
//import org.junit.Before;
//import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Selenium_SX extends SeleneseTestCase {

//      public class Jun3 
        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox3 C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "http://www.google.co.in/");
            selenium.start();
        }
//      C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Test
        public void test()  {
            selenium.open("http://www.google.com");
            selenium.windowMaximize();
//          selenium.waitForPageToLoad("5000");
//          selenium.type("id=acpro_inp3", "selenium");
            selenium.type("q", "software");
            selenium.click("btnG");
            selenium.waitForPageToLoad("7000");
//          selenium.fireEvent("Selenium web application testing system", "click");
//          selenium.click("link=Selenium web application testing system");  
//          selenium.click("xpath=//html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/ol/li[1]/div/span/h3/a");
            selenium.click("xpath=(//a[class=\"li[1]\"])[1]");

//          selenium.click("css=//div['span.tl h3.r a.l']");
            selenium.waitForPageToLoad("15000");            
        }

        @After
        public void tearDown()  {
            selenium.stop();
        }
//      public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
//          Selenium_SX sx=new Selenium_SX();
//          sx.setUp();
//          sx.test();
//          sx.tearDown();
//      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are waiting for enough time before executing the click command?

Comment: Can you add your source code.

Comment: please find code in the edited post and please suggest.Also, when I add waitforpagetoload after clicking search button, I get a timed out error though I increased time to 15000 sec.So I tried commenting the wait statement at the time of my first post here

Comment: You did not mention the specific error in your post. Can you please add the exact error specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note, **Google has a ban on automated queries**. I was using Google to test when I was new to testing, now I use our own server.

What you are looking for is this:

```
//a[contains(text(), 'software')]
```

This selects the first link with "software" in the link text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath `(//a[@class="l"])[1]`

Comment: Tried both the below ones, but they did not work. selenium.click("xpath=(//a[@class=\"link\"])[1]"); selenium.click("xpath=(//a[@class=\"l\"])[1]");

Answer (score 0):

there must be pause ( pause (1) ) or waitForElementPresent between 2 clicks
here is working sample for phpUnit. Strange, but clickAndWait does'n work

```
$this->open("/");
$this->type("q", "software");
$this->click("btnG");
for ($second = 0; ; $second++) {
    if ($second >= 60) $this->fail("timeout");
    try {
        if ($this->isElementPresent("//a[@class='l']")) break;
    } catch (Exception $e) {}
    sleep(1);
}

$this->click("//a[@class='l']");
```