# Please provide selenium rc code

Tags: selenium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XPATH or css in selenium RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328547/xpath-or-css-in-selenium-rc)

I am trying to automate the below scenario in selenium rc using java:

1.open google page
2.enter software in search text box
3.click on search button
4.from the resultant google result, click on the first link

I am trying to use xpath or css for clicking on link, but unable to succeed.
the same xpath and css work fine in selenium ide but fail in rc

can someone please help me and try to automate the above scenario and please share the code.

Thanks for your time

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Can you post the code you have that shows what you are trying to do and where it is going wrong? Asking "Please provide code" is unlikely to get positive response unless you show what *you* have done to solve your problem.

Comment: Just wondering, but why do you need to trigger this behavior in Google? You could always screenscrape the first result using searches in the format: `http://www.google.com/search?q=wikipedia&btnI=I'm feeling lucky`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

public class SampleTest extends SeleneseTestCase{
  @Test
  public void sampleTest() throws Exception
  {
   setUp("http://www.google.com","*iexplore");
   selenium.windowMaximize();
   selenium.windowFocus();
   selenium.open("/");
   selenium.type("q", "Software");
   selenium.click("btnG");
   selenium.waitForPageToLoad("");
  for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
            try 
            { 
              if (selenium.isElementPresent("link=Computer software - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"))
                  break;
              }
            catch (Exception e) {}
              Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

```
    selenium.click("link=Computer software - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia");
```

}

}